# why does Virtualbox use 15-20% CPU when VM is paused?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, cpu-usage

I run VirtualBox 3.1 on Ubuntu with a Win XP guest. I have noticed to my surprise that when I pause the VM (its screen grays out) VirtualBox continues using 15-20% of the host's CPU.

Is this normal behavior?

Is there a way to avoid it? (Without saving the state of the VM and exiting VirtualBox.)

Thanks for any insights!

~lara

Comment: Technically did VirtualBox ever claim pausing is supposed to reduce resources? See [Clarify if clicking to pause a guest releases CPU and/or Memory](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/21188).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to lessen VirtualBox CPU usage at all times, resort to this weird hack.

Create a new virtual machine and do not install an operating system to it. Tell VirtualBox it will run DOS and give it the absolute minimum resources. Do not install an O/S. Run it, let it error out on boot and minimize it.

While running your real O/S in a second VM, you will see your idle Virtualbox CPU utilization drop to 3-5%.

Idea from jed4czar:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=58e862a814e65eb96f8fe8389b615366&t=838073&page=2

**EDIT:** To answer your questions directly

> why does Virtualbox use 15-20% CPU
>   when VM is paused?

It is a bug. It is always using 15-20% more CPU than it needs to, when any one VM is up, unless the hack provided is used.

> Is there a way to avoid it?

See hack above.

Comment: nice to know, that vbox allocates possibliy used cpu-sources on startup

Comment: ooooh it fixed it for me too! Awesome, thanks. For info, I'm running windows 8.1, VM is centos and was consumming at idle time around 15% cpu. VBox v4.3.12

Comment: Amazing this is still an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the hack described above with the DOS VM, but with no success (running Ubuntu 12.04 guests on a MacBook Pro with OS X).  I also tried the kernel parameter changes mentioned in the [Oracle thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/9273399), again no change.  No matter what I did, my guests seemed to eat 15-20% CPU each.  However, I noticed that the one guest I happened to assign 2 CPUs was not chewing 15-20% - it was behaving as expected.

Sure enough, when I switched the others to 2 CPU's the issue disappeared.  From previous experience, I know that switching to 2 CPUs also enables the IO APIC option in the motherboard section so I suspected that was the truly interesting change.  That is, this one:

[image: IOAPIC Enabled]

Note that you have to have the machine shut down to change this setting, otherwise it is greyed out.  Once I had enabled this on the guests and restart, it didn't matter if I had 1 or more CPUs, the 15-20% CPU utilization went away, so I thought I would share my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Windows 7 Quad box running Oracle 5 in the VM.

Following Adam's advice i checked the Enabled IO APIC option but to no avail. So, i followed kmarsh's idea, which took probably less than a minute to try, and processor usage went down from 15-20% to 4-5%.

The settings used were, Name: Memory Hack, Type: Other, Version: DOS. Memory Size: 4MB, Hard Drive: Do not add a virtual hard drive. Click [Create]. Starting the VM asks for a start-up disk, i used: Host Drive 'D:', click [Start]. Virtual machine states: "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted." At that point, the cpu usage dropped, so i minimized the window. Starting a second VM makes no difference.

Comment: It appears this issue is so complex that no one tweak will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this VirtualBox issue on a 2-cpu P4 machine with 3gigs ram running CentOS 5.5 host.

I did not experience this issue on an i720 8cpu machine with 8 gigs running 64-bit Win7.  I ran 3 VMWare virtual machines plus the VirtualBox, all with 2-gigs memory, and had no CPU issues whatsoever.

This suggests either running on a "smallish" machine or on a Linux host is the problem.

Your solution worked well, thanks.

I note that these earlier posts are a year old, and my VirtualBox is the most recent Version 4.0.4, so Oracle has not fixed this bug yet.

Comment: I would expect that this performance penalty is associated with the face that newer CPUs have VT-x and similar to allow hardware assisted virtualisation which would mean that the VirtualBox program is not doing the work and therefore lower CPU usage. A P4 would likely not have the VT-x technology and so would have to translate system calls via software and use more CPU as a result.

Comment: This must have been fixed by now. using Ubuntu host and XP guest running VirtualBox v4.3.6 when I pause the guest, CPU usage drops bellow 1%

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not explain or fix the bug for me (Debian host, paused Ubuntu guest). Oracle has a section for this:

> Some Linux guests may cause a high CPU load even if the guest system
>   appears to be idle. This can be caused by a high timer frequency of
>   the guest kernel. Some Linux distributions, for example Fedora, ship a
>   Linux kernel configured for a timer frequency of 1000Hz. We recommend
>   to recompile the guest kernel and to select a timer frequency of
>   100Hz.
>
> Linux kernels shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux, as well as
>   kernels of related Linux distributions, such as CentOS and Oracle
>   Linux, support a kernel parameter divider=N. Hence, such kernels
>   support a lower timer frequency without recompilation. We suggest you
>   add the kernel parameter divider=10 to select a guest kernel timer
>   frequency of 100Hz.

Source: [Linux Guests May Cause a High CPU load](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/ts_lin-x11-guests.html)